# Required certificate key usage for signing document

Tags: signature, certificates

What's the required key usage/extended key usage for signing documents, eg.PDF, Word, PowerPoint, Excel, etc...

I am going to create a self-signed certificate that is needed to sign those documents. I wonder which key usage is required as there are many types that I can choose.

Note: I just need a self-signed certificate, not from trusted CAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use key usage as `digitalSignature` only to create a self-signed signing certificate for signing documents.

You can also use Microsoft proprietary `Document Signing` EKU: https://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3.10.3.12.html.

Additionally, you can add the following:

1. keyUsage

   - nonRepudiation (Good to have, since CA add this in document signing
     certificate)
2. extendedKeyUsage/EnhancedKeyUsage:

   - 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3.10.3.12 (Microsoft Document Signing)
   - 1.2.840.113583.1.1.5 (Adobe Authentic Documents Trust)

For more information, you can refer below URL:

https://www.globalsign.com/en/repository/GlobalSign_DocumentSign_for_Adobe_CDS_CPS_v1.3.pdf

Comment: With the release of [RFC 9336](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9336), there is now a standardized `id-kp-documentSigning` EKU (OID [`1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.36`](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.36)) available to use, though given how recently it was published, many applications may not yet support it.